# Does the CSS position relative have a performance impact on DOM rendering?

Tags: css, performance

I have a *habit* of setting `position: relative` on most of my DOM elements when I apply a *display* style.

```
.something {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

It is something that I've been doing for a few years now, and recently I had a discussion with someone who stated that setting many of these will *slow* down rendering in the web browser.

Is there anything in the CSS specifications or guidelines that states that it should be set sparingly?

I'm looking for a specific answer that states `position: relative` has X cost in performance, or creditable references that it has no cost.

Comment: Is there a reason why you preemptively do this? Seems like it could cause more harm than good

Comment: This isn't a good practice amigo. [Position](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_position.asp) `static` is default for a reason.

Comment: @zgood it's just a habit. My IDE makes it really easy to write display block then position relative. I do it, because it saves my time in going back later to make it relative, but I do admit it might be a bad habit.

Comment: Logically relative is more computationally expensive for a browser since it will need to take into account an offset parent when calculating positioning in contrast to static positioning in which most positioning calculations simply have no effect. However I have no real source to back this. By the same logic relative and absolute positioning should be about the same computationally

Comment: @CrazyPaste thanks for the answer, but as it stands it reads like an opinion. I understand this is a difficult question to answer specifically, but the nature of this website is to avoid broad questions. So I'm looking for insight into how the web browser handles rendering and why this would affect performance.

Comment: @cgTag I understand.  I wasn't aiming to answer based on opinion.  Most of my answer is objective.  Seems like you want more in depth specifics on how web browsers use CSS.  I'll work on that and modify my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer suggesting you try toggling `relative` and observe that it's "instantaneous" is speculative, qualitative, and inaccurate.

Break the habit. Unnecessary `relative` slows down rendering. I once observed an accidental ~40% rendering speed improvement on a list component (think dozens-to-hundreds of rows) by removing a single unnecessary instance of `relative`.

It also implies to a future reader/maintainer of your code (potentially even future-you) that the `relative` had some purpose to begin with, and that future person may be hesitant to make changes as a result. Never leave needless code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Adding any CSS will always slow down your code, but for something so small, it will be minuscule and not worth worrying about.  There's nothing special about `display: block` that requires you setting a position value.  What **is** important  that it's bad practice to always be adding this unless you know that you need it.

I'd drop the habit and only use `position: relative` on a per case basis.

As pointed out in the comments, `position: static` is default.

**Edit:**

You mentioned you're looking for some research showing performance impact of this CSS rule.  Here's a great article on the topic:

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

**Edit, Local test:**

Inspect element on the  StackOverflow home page.  Each post is an element with a class `question-summary`.  Add a new CSS rule:

```
.question-summary{
    position: absolute;
    position: relative;
}
```

Make sure both are rules are active.  Then check and uncheck `position: relative`.  Notice that it happens instantaneously.  This is rendering a bunch of elements.  *If you want to test further, copy and paste the `question-summary` divs and add hundreds of them.  Then repeat the test.  Notice how the browser renders this instantly.*

**Edit #2:**

There's some articles out there breaking down how web browsers and browser engines work under the hood, this is complicated and you'll need to study it. This seems to be a good place to start:
http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#Webkit_CSS_parser

If you want to learn past the articles you find online, you may need to dig into the web browser's engine's source code.  Webkit is common and open source:
https://webkit.org/

Again, if you don't want to dive into understanding web browser CSS interpretation, you'll need to rely on testing.  Developers generally spend their time optimizing for JavaScript rather than CSS, so there's not a lot out there.  I did find this:

https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/